# How to create and clone a JSON object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I was wondering how can I create a JSON (JS) object and then clone it.

Comment: Why *"can`t [you] work anymore with javascript array"*? JSON is just the array and object literal syntax of Javascript. If you like JSON syntax you should feel right at home when using arrays and objects in Javascipt.

Comment: Take some time and read this article: [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How to create a JSON object in javascript/jquery?

There is nothing like a JSON *object*. JSON stands for *JavaScript Object Notation* and is basically a string that encodes information similar to JavaScript's object literals.

You can however create such an encoding (which would result in a *string*) with `JSON.stringify(object)`, see [JSON in JavaScript](http://www.json.org/js.html). You could also create such a string manually, but it is very error prone and I don't recommend it.

> How do I clone a JSON object in javascript/jquery?

As it is just a string:

```
var jsonString2 = jsonString;
```

> I can`t work anymore with javascript arrays

JSON is a format to *exchange* data, it is not a data structure you can use in an application.

---

Maybe you want to read more about [JSON](http://www.json.org/), [objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects) in JS and [arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Predefined_Core_Objects#Array_Object) in JS.

Comment: The second answer is NOT true. The "=" operator will not clone any object but passing the reference.

Comment: @Reinhard: I never claimed that it does. **JSON** in JS only exists as a **string**. And since strings are immutable, cloning a string is as simple as assigning it to a different variable. Though I agree that in hindsight, the OP may have been talking about JavaScript objects.

Comment: @FelixKling: Then it is an answer to an invalid question. It follows it is not an answer. I think it would be better to remove that line to not confuse drive-by-readers and spread mis-wisdom.

Comment: -1 for the same reasons as Sebastian. People will be coming here looking for how to clone a JavaScript object and this answer is at best inadequate if not very misleading.

Comment: This answer is invalid. It does **NOT** clone a JSON array. What it does is that it will create a reference to the JSON array and will change the "clone" and the original array.

Comment: @Matthew: I think you are missing the context. This is about JSON (i.e. text), not JavaScript objects/arrays. If you are working with JavaScript arrays, then this answer is not for you. Please also note that the question was changed / updated 6 years after I posted this answer.

Comment: If so, the title misrepresents this question and needs to be updated to accurately inform people what is being asked.

Comment: Is a JSON object (I just realized I typed array instead) not a key/pair object? I just tested in the browser's console `foo = {"x":"y"}; bar= foo; bar.x = "z"; console.log("Foo: "+foo.x+" | Bar: "+bar.x")` and it changed both of them to `z`. Are we talking about a String object that contains JSON formatted data or a JSON object?

Comment: This seems like pedantry and is very misleading.  The = operator will not clone a "JavaScript object" to use the @Reinhard terminology.  Obviously this is what the poster was asking about.  

Now... I have to go to the ATM machine.

Answer (score 62):

This is what I do and it works like a charm

```
if (typeof JSON.clone !== "function") {
    JSON.clone = function(obj) {
        return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj));
    };
}
```

Comment: @Gobliins Yes it does

Comment: But it's worth mentioning that it's converting objects like Dates into strings, etc.

Comment: Nice, I haven't found out other ways to do a deep copy other than this.

Answer (score 28):

Just do

```
var x = {} //some json object here
var y = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(x)); //new json object here
```

Comment: This approach seems to give rise to some conversion issues between datatypes, in the case of nested JSON objects also including key associated to Array objects. In my case, the cloned object yielded key : {}, instead of the original key : []
The approach in the post below looks, newjsonobj = {...jsonobj}, looks like preferable

Comment: It's worth mentioning that this answer (not Sandro's comment) is converting objects like Dates into strings, etc

Answer (score 24):

As of ES6. Object.assign is a good way to do this.

```
newjsonobj = Object.assign({}, jsonobj, {})
```

The items in the first argument mutate the existing object, and the third argument are changes in the new object returned.

In ES7 it is proposed that the spread operator be used.

```
newjsonobj = {...jsonobj}
```

Comment: This creates a shallow clone: Any modifications to the values in the first JSON object will affect the clone (and vice versa), if those values are something mutable like objects or arrays. e.g. `var a = {arr:[1,2,3]}; var b = Object.assign({}, a, {}); b.arr[0] = 4; console.log(a.arr);` prints out `[4, 2, 3]` instead of `[1, 2, 3]` as expected.

Answer (score 12):

This is an issue I have often met when parsing JSON and reusing it several times in the code. And you want to avoid re-parsing every time from the original JSON string, or going the `serialize/parse` way which is the less efficient way.

So in these cases where you want to adjust the parsed object but still keep the original unchanged, use the following function in both server (**NodeJs**) or client javascript code. The jQuery `clone` function is less efficient because they treat the cases for functions, regexp, etc. The function below, only treats the JSON supported types (null, undefined, number, string, array and object):

```
function cloneJSON(obj) {
    // basic type deep copy
    if (obj === null || obj === undefined || typeof obj !== 'object')  {
        return obj
    }
    // array deep copy
    if (obj instanceof Array) {
        var cloneA = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; ++i) {
            cloneA[i] = cloneJSON(obj[i]);
        }              
        return cloneA;
    }                  
    // object deep copy
    var cloneO = {};   
    for (var i in obj) {
        cloneO[i] = cloneJSON(obj[i]);
    }                  
    return cloneO;
}
```

Comment: best answer. all the other solutions have their vulnerabilities. upvote this one to save other people's time

Answer (score 7):

**Q1**: **How to create a JSON object in javascript/jquery?**

Creating a Javascript object is so simple:

```
var user = {}; // creates an empty user object
var user = {firstName:"John", lastName:"Doe"}; // creates a user by initializing 
// its firstName and lastName properties.
```

After the creation you can add extra fields to your object like `user.age = 30;`.

If you have the object as a JSON string, you can convert it to a JSON object using built-in `JSON.parse(yourJsonString)` function or jQuery's `$.parseJSON(yourJsonString)` function.

**Q2**: **How do I clone a JSON object in javascript/jquery?**

My way to clone JSON objects is [extend](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/) function of jQuery. For example, you can generate a clone of your user object like below:

```
var cloneUser = $.extend(true, {}, {firstName:"John", lastName:"Doe"});
```

The first parameter designates whether the clone object will be a shallow or deep copy of the original (see [Object copy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_copy) on wiki).

To see other JSON cloning alternatives you can read [this](http://heyjavascript.com/4-creative-ways-to-clone-objects/) article.

Comment: `JSON.parse` returns an `Object`(See: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse#Return_value)), not a "JSON object", which AFAIK does not exist. (Not to nitpick but this is a point of confusion for many beginners so it might be good to correct it)

Answer (score 1):

We can clone JSON object as below.

```
EmployeeDetails = 
{
  Name:"John Deer",
  Age:29,
  Company:"ABC Limited."

}
```

Now create one clone function

```
function clonning(Employee)
{
  // conversion from Object to String
  var EmployeeString = JSON.stringify(Employee);

  // conversion from String to Object type

  var EmployeeConvertedObject = JSON.parse(EmployeeString);

  // printing before changing prperty value.

  console.log(EmployeeConvertedObject);

  // modifying EmployeeConvertedObject property value 

  EmployeeConvertedObject.Name="Kelvin Bob";

   // printing After changing prperty value.

  console.log(EmployeeConvertedObject);

  // Now printing original json object.

  console.log(Employee);

  // Here original JSON object is not affecting. Only Cloned object affecting.


}
```

Now Call function.

```
clonning(EmployeeDetails);
```

Result:

```
clonning(EmployeeDetails)
VM212:22 {Name: "John Deer", Age: 29, Company: "ABC Limited."}
VM212:30 {Name: "Kelvin Bob", Age: 29, Company: "ABC Limited."}
VM212:34 {Name: "John Deer", Age: 29, Company: "ABC Limited."}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's suppose,
We have a JSONOBJECT EmailData which have some Data in it. Now if you want the same data in another object (i.e clone the data) then you can do something like this:

```
JSONOBJECT clone_EmailData=new JSONOBJECT(EmailData.toString());
```

The above statement will give you a new object with the same data and the new object is not a reference to the EmailData object.