# JavaScript Exception "The object invoked has disconnected from its clients." on window.open(...)

Tags: javascript, window.open

I have a JavaScript file attached to a webpage called 'navigate.js' It contains a collection of methods that look like this:

```
var ContractWindow;
function showContract(ContractID){
    try{
         if(ContractWindow){
            if(!ContractWindow.closed){
               ContractWindow.close;
            }
         }

        ContractWindow = window.open(contract.aspx?contractid=" + ContractID, "ContractEditor",
        "toolbar=0,location=0,directories=0,status=0,menubar=0,scrollbars=0,resizable=1,width=780,height=615");
        }
    }catch(exc){
    alert(exc.message);
    }
}
```

(there are similar functions to open pages for editing product categories, products, regions...etc.)

Each of several functions opens up a different editor page *in its own window*, with the goal that only one window of any given type (where type="ContractEditor") should be open at any given time.

If an editor (in this case the Contract Editor) is reused we want to close the previous window first so that subsequent `window.open` will cause the new window to come to front of any windows (have focus).

*Everything works as expected* until the page has been idle for approximately 10 minutes. After which the alert message reads: **The object invoked has disconnected from its clients**

Various tests have revealed that the exception comes from the assignment of the return value of window.open to the ContractWindow variable. If I leave out `ContractWindow =` and just call `window.open`, it works but the window does not 'pop' to the forefront which is a requirement. (window.open reuses the existing window named "ContractEditor" but does not bring it forward from the stack of open windows.)

Comment: Are you running Microsoft VBA code?

Comment: No. Asp.net/C# on the server with javascript (and some jquery) on the client. The browser is IE 7/8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While better answers are certainly welcome I have arrived at a 'work around' that will serve to get the feature 'out the door' though I would like to get a better understanding of the cause of this exception and a 'better solution' if it exists.

Having determined that the issue arises from the attempt to assign the return value of `window.open` to `var ContractWindow` I introduced a layer of mis-direction as follows:

```
var ContractWindow;
function showContract(ContractID){
    try{
         if(ContractWindow){
            if(!ContractWindow.closed){
               ContractWindow.close;
            }
         }
        // assign the return of window.open to a 'guaranteed new' variable...
        var newWindow = window.open(contract.aspx?contractid=" + ContractID, "ContractEditor",
        "toolbar=0,location=0,directories=0,status=0,menubar=0,scrollbars=0,resizable=1,width=780,height=615");
        // then re-assign to the global var ContractWindow.
        ContractWindow = newWindow;
        }
    }catch(exc){
    alert(exc.message);
    }
}
```

I am thinking there must be something different in the way JavaScript manages object pointers... 
What I have done 'works' but it is not what I would call 'good'... 
Then again there is always this corollary to *Murphy's Law*:

> If it's stupid but it works, it isn't stupid.

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem with my code, 
try to [colne](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4120475/how-to-create-clone-a-json-in-javascript-jquery) the that you get from `window.open`, becuse he depand on `open.window` status.

i used `jQuery.extend(true, {}, data);` to clone the data i get from window.open.
it may work for you.