# Clone "sub-array" of an array of objects (where objects are deeply nested)

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, clone

Question 1. I was wondering why

```
JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj.slice(1, 3))) and
obj.slice(1,3)
```

give the same nested array of objects as output since `obj.slice(1,3)` is not supposed to clone nested objects properly?

Question 2. Is `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj.slice(1, 3)))` the right way to deep clone a sub-array?

**obj details -**

```
var obj= [{ name: "wfwfwfw.)csdfsd",
        tags: [ "dfbdf>>sfdfds", "fsdfsdf&fsfd" ],
        newer: { first: "this'one", second: ["that>.one", "another.'one"], third: {something: "some/>fded", newthing: "ddasd..>sqw"}     },
        final: [ {gh: "ty/fgfg", hj: "rt((ssds"}, {gh: "dqqq...g", hj: "gnm))s"} ]
},
{ name: "wfwfwwwwwwfw.)csdfsd",
        tags: [ "dfbdf>>sfdfds", "fsdfsdf&fsfd" ],
        newer: { first: "this'one", second: ["that>.one", "another.'one"], third: {something: "some/>fded", newthing: "ddasd..>sqw"} },
        final: [ {gh: "ty/fgfg", hj: "rt((ssds"}, {gh: "dqqq...g", hj: "gnm))s"}]
},
{ name: "aa.)csdfsd",
        tags: [ "dfbdf>>sfdfds", "fsdfsdf&fsfd" ],
        newer: { first: "this'one", second: ["that>.one", "another.'one"], third: {something: "some/>fded", newthing: "ddasd..>sqw"} },
        final: [ {gh: "ty/fgfg", hj: "rt((ssds"}, {gh: "dqqq...g", hj: "gnm))s"}]
},
{ name: "nn.)csdfsd",
        tags: [ "dfbdf>>sfdfds", "fsdfsdf&fsfd" ],
        newer: { first: "this'one", second: ["that>.one", "another.'one"], third: {something: "some/>fded", newthing: "ddasd..>sqw"} },
        final: [ {gh: "ty/fgfg", hj: "rt((ssds"}, {gh: "dqqq...g", hj: "gnm))s"}]
}]
```

Comment: `obj.slice(1,3)` and `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj.slice(1, 3)))` give the same output because they do exactly the same thing.  One just takes longer to get there.

Comment: Does that mean that obj.slice(1,3) can be used for deep cloning objects?

Comment: No.  slice is just copying references.  The references in the result returned by `obj,slice` are the same ones as in `obj`.  `JSON.stringify` creates strings from your objects, then `JSON.parse` turns the string into new objects with the same structure.  You get the same output because they are copies.  There is no way to tell them apart (except that they have different addresses in memory, i.e.  by using ===)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create and clone a JSON object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4120475/how-to-create-and-clone-a-json-object)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why should it make a difference if you `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify())` the result from `obj.slice(1, 3)`, or not? That's what's happening in example 1.

You get `obj.slice(1, 3)`, and you get the *same value*, passed through a stringify / parse.

Functionally, that's similar to:

```js
var foo = 'bar';
console.log(foo);
console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(foo)));
```

Regarding question 2:

Yeap.

`obj.slice` alone can't be used to clone objects. It just copies the *contents* of an array. In this case, those contents are just pointers to existing objects:

```js
var a = [{foo: 'bar'}, {x: 'y'}];
var b = a.slice(0,1) 

console.log('B:', b);

b[0].foo = 'test';

console.log('After modification:');
console.log('A:', a);
console.log('B:', b);
```

As you can see, editing the `foo` on `b` also changes it on `a`, because both arrays contain pointers to the *same* object.

That's why you need the `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify())`.

Comment: So what would be the best way to clone a sub-array of objects?

Comment: But JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj)) would clone the whole array. What if I wanted to clone only obj[0], obj[1], obj[2] into a new array?

Comment: Then you first select the proper array entries with `slice`

Comment: Then, I guess `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj.slice(0, 3)))` is the right way to deep clone a sub-array?

Comment: In that case, you should not have written `No` as answer to Question 2 (in your answer)

Answer (score -1):

Array.slice() does not do deep copying, hence its not suitable for multidimensional arrays.

jQuery's extend method does perform a deep copy when a true value is passed as the initial argument.

```
// Deep copy
var newArray = jQuery.extend(true, [], oldArray);
```

similar post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-deep-clone-an-object-in-javascript)