# Import/Require JSON file as clone into Vue data property

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-2016

I am having an issue with using external data within a Vue `data` property.

Consider the following snippet from my component:

```
export default {

    data() {
        return {
            gallery: require('core-js/support/some-page-gallery.json')
        }
    },

    created() {

        // Prepare the images for the gallery
        this._buildImageURLs();

    },

    methods: {

        /**
         * Build the image urls for the gallery.
         *
         * @return void
         */
        _buildImageURLs() {

            this.gallery.forEach(image => {
                Object.entries(image.images).forEach(([key, source]) => {
                    image.images[key] = this.$staticAsset(`/assets/images/misc/${source}`);
                });
            });

        }

    }

}
```

The issue with the above is that modifying `this.gallery` seems to modify the originally imported array.

This results in the following:

- On page load, `image.images[0]` is equal to `example.com/assets/images/misc/example.jpg`
- When navigating away, and then back to that page, `image.images[0]` is equal to `example.com/assets/images/misc/example.com/assets/images/misc/example.jpg`

What is the best way to `require` my JSON file as a clone instead of as a reference? Assuming that is what is going wrong here...

Alternatively, is there a better way to import the data into my component?

## What have I tried?

I have also tried using `import` but this results in exactly the same result.

In addition, I have thought about passing `this.gallery` as a parameter to `this._buildImageURLs()` and I am fairly confident I could get this to work but I am hesitant as it doesn't seem like the correct way to do this.

## Update

Just in case the above is not clear; the issue I am facing is that `this.gallery` is acting as a reference to the imported file. As a result, the imported data is maintaining it's edited state throughout my application.

When I first last on the page, the `_buildImageURLs` method amends the data correctly. But if I navigate away, and then back to the page, the modified data is modified again which results in duplicate modifications.

Comment: Its not possible for you to be updating the actual json file with the code you have there, having that said I'm not sure what are you trying to accomplish, can you clarify, please?

Comment: @DavidPorcel - I am aware that you cannot update the json file, that is not what I am trying to accomplish. I am trying to import a clone of the data within the json file. It seems that when the json file is imported, it keeps it state throughout my app. In other words, if I make changes to the imported object, those changes are still present when I navigate back to the page that made the modifications....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to copy the JSON before do any mutation on the forEach statement:

```
const GALLERY = require('core-js/support/some-page-gallery.json');

export default {

    data(){
        retrun {
            gallery: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(GALLERY)); 
        }
    }

    //rest of your code...
}
```

Check this question: [How to create and clone a JSON object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4120475/how-to-create-and-clone-a-json-object)

Comment: I originally had a computed property actually, I only moved away from it because it was resulting in the same issue. That's an interesting way of doing this in regards to parsing the JSON. I would make one change to your answer though; having `gallery` and `getGallery` is unnecessary. It's better to just create a `gallery` computed property and parse the imported json in there

Comment: Eh? The computed property is resolved on creation and then subsequently updated if any used properties change... It has nothing to do with props

Comment: For future reference, that's not true. If you create a computed property that simply mutates a static object (not connected to any props/data values), it is fired upon component creation. I am doing exactly this at the moment and it works :-D

Answer (score 0):

You could make a copy of `gallery` using `Object.assign` like this:

`export default {

```
data() {
    return {
        gallery: require('core-js/support/some-page-gallery.json'),
        galleryClone: {}
    }
},

created() {

    // Prepare the images for the gallery
    this._buildImageURLs();

},

methods: {

    /**
     * Build the image urls for the gallery.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    _buildImageURLs() {
        this.galleryClone = Object.assign({}, ...this.gallery);
        Object.entries(this.galleryClone).forEach(([key, value]) => 
        {
            Object.entries(this.galleryClone[key].images).forEach(([key, source]) => {
                this.galleryClone[key].images[key] = this.$staticAsset(`/assets/images/misc/${source}`);
            });
        });

    }

}
```

}`

what this is doing is passing the value of `gallery` to `galleryClone` by value and not by reference. Then you could use the `galleryClone` variable on your component instead of `gallery` whenever you need to update its contents.

Comment: This is a very dirty solution... I won't down vote it as it technically answers the question, but I would strongly encourage you not to write code in this way unless there is no other solution

Comment: I was going for a solution that involved the least amount of changes to the code you posted, but I completely agree that is not an elegant solution, using a computed property or a watcher instead of what it is on the created method could acomplish the same thing in a cleaner way